# How to check if Maven is running in offline mode in JUnit tests running with the maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: maven, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

Is it possible to somehow check, if Maven is running in offline mode? I'd like to trigger a profile that excludes certain tests, if there is no connection to the internet.

Comment: How are unit tests related to offline/online mode of Maven? Running in offline modes does not mean there is no internet connection...Apart from that this sounds more like integration tests which should be done by maven-failsafe-plugin...What is the purpose of the test?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Yes, they are in effect integration tests, but they require a connection to the internet. Obviously, while you're coding on the train/subway, your internet connection won't be the best, (if there's any at all). So, I would like to come up with a solution where, if I simply do `mvn -o ...`, this would be picked up and these tests would be excluded. Is there some property in Maven that translates to `mvn -o`, or something else that could be used? (Yeah, clearly, I can have yet another profile for this case and trigger it manually, but I've been hoping for a better solution).